# How to fix connection pool leak in Grails?

Tags: grails, connection-pooling

This is with Grails 2.4.4.  I'm encountering a connection pool leak that seems to have to do with Grails transaction management.  Anybody have an idea of where the the problem lies?

Suspect leak detection message from Tomcat JDBC Pool:

```
015-06-11 13:44:03,483 [PoolCleaner[2120388162:1434055276957]] [||] WARN  pool.ConnectionPool  - Connection has been marked suspect, possibly abandoned PooledConnection[org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@4fcf9353][89657 ms.]:java.lang.Exception
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1063)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:780)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:619)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:403)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:240)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at groovy.sql.Sql$CreatePreparedStatementCommand.execute(Sql.java:4512)
at groovy.sql.Sql$CreatePreparedStatementCommand.execute(Sql.java:4491)
at groovy.sql.Sql.getAbstractStatement(Sql.java:4342)
at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:4357)
at groovy.sql.Sql.getPreparedStatement(Sql.java:4434)
at groovy.sql.Sql.access$900(Sql.java:228)
at groovy.sql.Sql$PreparedQueryCommand.runQuery(Sql.java:4622)
at groovy.sql.Sql$AbstractQueryCommand.execute(Sql.java:4553)
at groovy.sql.Sql.rows(Sql.java:1954)
at groovy.sql.Sql.firstRow(Sql.java:2192)
at groovy.sql.Sql$firstRow.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
...
```

In resources.groovy:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
beans = {
    sql(Sql, ref("dataSource"));
}
```

In DataSource.groovy:

```
dataSource {
url = "jdbc:postgresql:testdb"
username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"
driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"
pooled = true
jmxEnabled = true
readOnly = false
autoCommit = false
properties {
    initialSize = 1
    maxActive = 15
    minIdle = 1
    maxIdle = 2
    maxWait = 20000 // 20 seconds
    maxAge = 20 * 60000 // 20 minutes
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 15000
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 10000
    validationQueryTimeout = 10 // 10 seconds
    validationInterval = 15000 // 15 seconds
    testOnBorrow = true
    testWhileIdle = true
    testOnReturn = false
    logValidationErrors = true
    removeAbandonedTimeout = 60 * 1440 // 24 hours, use suspectTimeout instead
    removeAbandoned = true // needed for suspectTimeout
    suspectTimeout = 60
    logAbandoned = true // needed for suspectTimeout logging
    validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
}
}
```

TestController.groovy:

```
class TestController {
  def testService

  def test() {
    Integer id = testService.test()
    render "Testing: $id\n"
  }
}
```

TestService.groovy:

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class TestService {
    def sql

    @Transactional
    Integer test() {
        def row = sql.firstRow("select id from TestTable where name = 'Test'")
        return row.id
    }
}
```

The leak detection message doesn't show if the query is moved from the transactional service to the controller, and I assume this is because the controller isn't transactional.

It also doesn't report a leak message if I change in resources.groovy to using the Unproxied version of the dataSource:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
beans = {
    sql(Sql, ref("dataSourceUnproxied"));
}
```

Digging down into the actual groovy.sql.Sql code, it looks to me that the problem is related to the fact that firstRow() opens and closes its own connection from the pool using a try {} finally{} block.  But the connection that it gets is proxied via a Spring TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy.

In the proxy source code, I see:

```
else if (method.getName().equals("close")) {
    // Handle close method: only close if not within a transaction.                             
    ConnectionFactoryUtils.doReleaseConnection(this.target, this.connectionFactory);
    return null;
}
```

Ok, so the underlying connection doesn't get released back to the pool if within a transaction?  This isn't making much sense to me because it will always be within a transaction in a @Transactional service method, so the connection will never get closed unless there's code somewhere else in Grails or Spring that will close() a connection after a commit()?

Comment: you don''t need to declare it twice, at the top of the class if its for everything inside the class - or then declared further down per call if your service is going to be a mixed Service of non transactional and transactional. In regards to your actual issue, it be hard to say https://github.com/vahidhedayati/documentation/blob/master/grails/acid.md take a look here and maybe you can add REQUIRES_NEW see if it makes any difference.To better understand Grails transactions watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNey9T--rLE

Comment: Changing the propagation to REQUIRES_NEW does seem to prevent the leak detection message, but I'd sure like to understand why so I know where I'm supposed to use this throughout my code.  The default in Grails seems to be REQUIRED.  Does this mean I should change the default propagation behavior to REQUIRES_NEW app-wide, or should I only be using @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) on my service entry method only  (i.e., the method that the Controller calls) and rely on the default of REQUIRED for the other methods?

Comment: Something odd I spotted, why do you have both the class and the method annotated as transactional? Try one or the other, not both. Not sure if that will matter (haven't looked at the AST for @transactional in a long time).

Comment: Also, you are aware that you are creating a single instance of sql which is being shared application wide, correct? Something about that seems off to me. Without looking deeper into the implementation and making sure it understands obtaining a new connection from the pool and returning it to the pool I'd be hesitant about using this approach. For all I know sql is stateful and multiple concurrent uses of it would be spelling disaster ...

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Yes, I've thought about that too and should have made it part of my question.  I've been told that Sql instances can be created as Spring beans and reused in this manner, but what I was told could be incorrect.  Here is a blog post that also shows making it a Spring bean: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-groovy-sql.html.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore **Update**: I tested this by creating a new Sql instance in the Service rather than using the Spring bean.  The connection leak message still appeared, so that appears to not be the issue.

Comment: Well, I'd trust that source (e.g. the blog post) to be spot on. Just something that I thought was worth checking. What about the multiple transaction annotations? Not that I think that will be the issue, but it's odd.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I had a `JmsTransactionManager` configured in `resources.groovy`.

It turns out I needed to also explicitly add the JDBC transaction manager.  I had to add the following to resources.groovy:

```
transactionManager(org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager, ref("dataSource"))
```

This gives me a `ChainedTransactionManager` with Grails that contains the `JmsTransactionManager` and the `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

I'm not using Hibernate.  If using Hibernate/GORM, instead of `DataSourceTransactionManager`, you'll want `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTransactionManager`.

Comment: I don't understand how this solved your problem and how declaring transactionManager bean solved your issue with leaking connections of sql bean ?